# No package 'pygtk-2.0' found

Tags: c++, package, zbar

i'll be quick:
I'm trying to use the zbar library but, already, while installing i had an issue. When i try to use the command in the zbar folder:

> ./configure --disable-video

the following error appear:

> > checking for PYGTK... configure: error: Package requirements (pygtk-2.0) were not met:
>
> No package 'pygtk-2.0' found
>
> Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
>   installed software in a non-standard prefix.
>
> Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PYGTK_CFLAGS and
>   PYGTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config. See the pkg-config
>   man page for more details.

I tried some things that i found but none could solve my issue.
Thanks for the future answers!

Answer (score 0):

It's a python package. Not sure what package manager you are using, but try to build in an environment where python is installed and pygtk is used. Alternatively, configure your build with --no-python. You will still get the lib but not all the apps.